# jQuery Slider does not work on Android Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/

The jQuery slider does not work on Android.
Can someone recommend a web-based slider that works on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery Mobile

http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: it seems very slow http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/ (on the default browser, CM10.1, Galaxy Tab 2 7.0). I wonder if I can reply just that widget and keep jqueryUI

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the jQuery Mobile Slider but it feels really slow.
I'm trying "[Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/)" now, very promising!!
As linked from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9533878/809536