# jQuery UI slider Touch & Drag/Drop support on Mobile devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, touch, jquery-ui-slider

I have already styled and implemented jQuery UI slider into a project. Though it's responsive, the slider does not respond to being touched and dragged. Instead, you have to touch where you want the slider to go. I'd like to avoid swapping to jQuery mobile UI, which supports touching and dragging, since we already extensively use jQuery (non-mobile) UI.

The functionality we want:
[Here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/about/getting-started.html)
What we are using: [Here](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps)

On a desktop you can't tell the difference. On a mobile device it is apparent.

Anyone know how to add this support to jquery UI?

```
$("#videographers").slider({
  value: 2,
  min: 1,
  max: 3,
  step: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    return calcTotal(ui.value);
  }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI sliders on touch devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360249/jquery-ui-sliders-on-touch-devices)

Answer (score 308, accepted):

jQuery ui doesn't have touch support. You should use it with [jQuery-ui touch punch](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui-touch-punch).

Just add the script after jQuery ui:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

You can also use cdnjs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

**Note:** Better give [this repo](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch) a star on Github.

Comment: Yes, it also fixed a bug with the slider not choosing the right values.

Comment: works like a charme with rails5 android and ios devices

Comment: great.. it works smoothly.. :)
One observation is that in iOS devices when we slide the slider it's not sliding when we touched it but when we release the touch from it then it slides at that point. any idea why this happens? do you have any solution for this?

Comment: This package last update was in 2014, so far it has been 10 years but it still works!

Answer (score 6):

You can just link this js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you are in **Wordpress** you can use this code in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {

    // jquery.ui.touch-punch
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.ui.touch-punch', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js', [], '0.2.3',false );

}, 999 );
```