# JQuery UI - Support for Touch Events Soon?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, touch

Is jquery UI being updated soon to support touch events? Many features made now in jquery ui don't work from a tablet (except when stylist or mouse is used, triggering the clicks).

Edit: Maybe this doesn't apply to all tablets. For the surface Pro 2, it does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI slider Touch & Drag/Drop support on Mobile devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808663/jquery-ui-slider-touch-drag-drop-support-on-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript Drag and drop for touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186441/javascript-drag-and-drop-for-touch-devices?rq=1)

I found this question which supplies a plugin that converts the touches to clicks for the jquery ui functions