# jQuery UI Slider does not work well in iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, jquery-ui, uislider

I have jquery ui slider it works good form laptop but if i test it form iphone or any touch screed device id doesn't work like normal iPhone app sliders , is there any way to make it work like iphone normal sliders ?

i am Using this code right now :

```
 var resolution= ["800 x 600", "1024 x 768", "1280 x 960", "1280 x 1024", "1600 x 1200", "1280 x 720", "1280 x 800", "1440 x 900", "1680 x 1050", "1920 x 1080", "All"]; 
 $(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({ 
       min: 0, 
       max: resolution.length-1, 
       orientation:"vertical",
       values: [resolution.length-1],
       slide: function( event, ui ) {
          $( "#size" ).val( resolution[ui.values[ 0 ]] );
       }
    })
 $( "#size" ).val("All");
 $('#slider').slider("float", {
    labels: resolution
  });
});
```

Comment: Any touch related scripts also attached in this HTML ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI sliders on touch devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360249/jquery-ui-sliders-on-touch-devices)

Comment: yes the Ui sources are attached ofcz

Comment: and thank you .. touch events is what i am looking for :)