# jQuery bootstrap slider not working smoothly in mobile device

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, mobile

I am using a pricing range slider below -

http://amirolahmad.github.io/bootstrap-pricing-slider/

Everything went well but I need to make the slider swipable in mobile device. From the following url I used `jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js` to make the slider swipable in mobile device - [jQuery UI sliders on touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360249/jquery-ui-sliders-on-touch-devices)

Now it is swiping the slider in mobile device. But it is not so much smooth and it crashes sometimes! I checked it in Samsung Galaxy Note 4 and Samsung Galaxy S5.

How can I make it smooth and will work without any crash?

Thanks in advance.